# How to delete a column on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, alter-table, sql-null

[image]

an easy way to delete the b_color column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends on what you mean by *delete a column*.

*If* you mean set all values to `null` in the column, then use `update`:

```
update mytable set b_color = null;
```

Disclaimer: original values are deleted for good. You might want to take a backup first.

*If* you mean permanently remove that column from the table, then use `drop column`:

```
alter table mytable drop column b_color;
```

Use the latter with caution! This is a data definition statement: once the column is gone, it cannot be retrieved any more - you need to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: nice way..I was to tired to see that it has a button to delete it..thanks anyway this will be helpful for many guys I think too

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `alter table` statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN b_color
```